# Как сделать так чтобы картинка менялась когда выбран radio button

Tags: radio

**Ресурс** - https://kruto.kz/test/8ozer/

Нажмите на "Бронировать", изменения нужно сделать в форме заполнения данных.

**Что нужно**

Чтобы при после нажатия на одну из иконок которые находятся после надписи "Выберите способ оплаты" картинка при состоянии hover оставалась, то есть становилась цветной.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно сделать так:

CSS (вводим новый css класс, при котором label'ы будут выглядеть цветными):

```
.terminal:hover, .terminal.hover {background-image: url(img/reserv/terminalOn.png);
.viza:hover, .viza.hover {background-image: url(img/reserv/visaOn.png);
.masterCard:hover, .masterCard.hover {background-image: url(img/reserv/mastercardOn.png);
```

JS:

```
$(".terminal, .viza, .masterCard").on('click', function() {
    // меняем css класс выбранному label'y, чтоб изменилась картинка
    $(".terminal, .viza, .masterCard").removeClass('hover');
    $(this).addClass('hover');

    // чекаем нужный радиобаттон
    $(this).find('input').prop("checked", true);
});
```